# Como usar o AutoFit no C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou exportando dados para uma planilha do Excel e não estou conseguindo usar o AutoFit, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Código:

```
public void exportarExcel(InformacaoDB info, string nomeArquivo)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Cliente";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Nome do Servidor";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Uso de Processamento (%)";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Uso de Armazenamento (%)";

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = info.Cliente;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = info.NomeServidor;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = info.UsoProcessamento;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = info.UsoArmazenamento;
}
```

Comment: O C# não possui nenhum `AutoFit`. É provável que a API usada possua, mas no seu código não tem nada que indique isto. Pode dar mais informações? Achei isto: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofit.aspx

Comment: Eu queria formatar as células do Excel pelo código C#, tipo Alinhamento, largura e altura automático, essas coisas.

Comment: @ThiagoBeltrame creio que você consiga resolver o problema da maneira que postei na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método `AutoFit` dessa maneira:

```
public void exportarExcel(InformacaoDB info, string nomeArquivo) {

    [...]

    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit();

    [...]
}
```

Uma coisa que creio que ajude muito, quando você quiser saber como fazer algo, vá no próprio Excel e grave uma macro do que você pretende fazer, depois é só ver o código no VBA do Excel e adaptar.